# Application running too slow, customer asked to up Immediate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Application is running too slow since 2 hrs. Customer escalated. What are the steps/Information I need to collect from the Customer and what can I reply customer and how to resolve the Issue?

Answer (score 0):

Run a SQL profiler and check the response time of all queries. Then you can get an idea of what are the queries that take long durations.

Also check if you indexes/Keys are properly implemented. I have notices some times when we get backups and restore the databased, some keys get dropped automatically in sql server.

You can also check the DB server available disk space as well.